# How do I properly use the Bootstrap Grid System Layout in my EmberJS App

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I'm wondering if anyone has found a way to implement [Bootstrap's Grid Layout](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/) system in their Ember JS app.

I've tried Ember Bootstrap, but they don't have the grid system included.  I also tried other NPM packages such as Bootstrap 3 Grid and Bootstrap 4.

What am I doing wrong that grid layouts won't display properly within my project?

I also had the following HTML wrapped in a `<div class="row">` for the columns but that didn't work at all either.

```
{{#each model as |phone|}}
  <div class="phone">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="phone-header">
        {{phone.make}} {{phone.model}}
          <small>{{phone.trim}}</small>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        Option 1
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        Option 2
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        Option 3
      </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

With clear fix:

```
 {{#each model as |phone|}}
      <div class="phone">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="phone-header">
            {{phone.make}} {{phone.model}}
              <small>{{phone.trim}}</small>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-4">
             Some Item Column
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
             Some Item Column
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-4">
             Some Item Column
          </div>
         {{twbs-clearfix columnCount=3 index=index visible-sm=true visible-md=true visible-lg=true}}
    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

I made sure my CSS and JS were imported properly, however I still don't get a grid layout when trying to layout items.

What am I missing?

Or should I just build a flexible layout the old way by hand?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying multiple NPM packages for Bootstrap installs for Ember, I finally just decided to download the source file from Bootstrap 4, add the original `bootstrap-grid-min.css`.

Go to my `app.css` then add: `@import url("bootstrap-grid.min.css");` above my secondary custom css. I'm sure there are more productive options but this option works.

Answer (score 1):

Need to wrap those `div`s with `<div class="row">`

```
<div class="phone">
  <div class="row"><!-- add this to specify the row -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="phone-header">
        {{phone.make}} {{phone.model}}
          <small>{{phone.trim}}</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      Option 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      Option 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      Option 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe definition is not clear at bootstrap guides. You may want to look to [the examples](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-basic)

Grid has totally 12 column.

Comment: I actually had it originally wrapped in a row and got no different of a result. Unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: all of them in a row? grid has totally 12 column. 12+4+4+4=24. Try: 6+2+2+2

Comment: I originally started by wrapping all columns in a `row` class div, but nothing works.

Comment: works in a regular static HTML project, not in a EmberJS application

Comment: ok, I'll update my answer as in one row. Totally 12 =  6+2+2+2

Comment: aha, if it is not working in emberjs application, some other css can override it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember to include bootstrap in your code!

Normally when I start an ember CLI project I do the following:

1. install `ember-cli-sass` (You could use `less` instead!)
2. install `ember-bootstrap`
3. rename `app.css` to `app.scss` (Sass extension for css)
4. Put the line `@import "ember-bootstrap/bootstrap";` right at the top of the `app.scss` file

I'm sure there is other methods of doing this, however I don't know them offhand!

Comment: Yeah I made sure to import everything and tried with SASS but nothing worked unfortunately.  I tried about 6 different NPM packages and got nothing to function how I needed it.  

However, I did just straight copy and paste `bootstrap-grid-min.css` from the Bootstrap 4 alpha and it's now working.  Go figure the old school method works!

Comment: Good to hear that something worked out for you, odd that nothing else worked though, what version of ember are you using?

Comment: Ember 2.12.2.  Very odd indeed, I had to install the CSS files manually then added `ember-bootstrap`.